# How do I change the value of a specific element when all the elements are the same?

Tags: c#, xml

Sorry to post another question the next day but im really stumped on how to get this to work. So in my program I got a form that when you click submit it's sopposed to change a specific element. But it gives an error "'lEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'SetElementValue'"

Can anyone help please? Here is my code.

```
        private void SubmitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string appDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
            string dataPath = Path.Combine(appDataPath, "Remembrall 2.0");
            string EventslistFullPath = Path.Combine(dataPath, "Events.xml");
            string[] Elementlist = new string[] { };
            Elementlist = XDocument.Load(EventslistFullPath).Descendants("Events").Elements("Event").Select(element => element.Value).ToArray();



            XElement EventDoc = XElement.Load(EventslistFullPath);

            var Eventselect = EventDoc.Descendants("Events"). Elements("Event").Where(eve => eve.Value == MainForm.ModDisc);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ModifyTexbox.Text) || Elementlist.Contains(ModifyTexbox.Text))

            {
                MessageBox.Show("Must be unique and have actual content.");
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
            }
            else
                Eventselect.SetElementValue("Event", ModifyTexbox.Text);

                EventDoc.Save(EventslistFullPath);
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

        }
```

The xml looks like this

```
<Events>
  <Event>This is an example</Event>
  <Event>This is another example</Event>
</Events>
```

Comment: you want to set the first or the second ``Event``?

Comment: List<XElement> events = doc.Descendants("Event").ToList().  Then change like any list item events[1].SetValue("Changed Value");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line:

```
 var Eventselect = EventDoc.Descendants("Events"). Elements("Event").Where(eve => eve.Value == MainForm.ModDisc);
```

to:

```
var Eventselect = EventDoc.Descendants("Events"). Elements("Event").Where(eve => eve.Value == MainForm.ModDisc).Single();
```

or to:

```
 var Eventselect = EventDoc.Descendants("Events"). Elements("Event").Single(eve => eve.Value == MainForm.ModDisc);
```

you need the variable to contain a single element for `SetElementValue(...)` to work. `Where(...)` without `Single(...)` returns an Enumerable of several elements

Comment: Thanks for answering. It allowed me to start the program but it comes with a sequance contains no matching element.

Forget I said anything. I fixed it by removing the descendants part.

Comment: Yeah, it might be better to use either `SingleOrDefault(...)` or `FirstOrDefault(...)` for your case.  `First...` will take the first matching element and `Single` will  only allow *one* matching element or it will throw. The `...OrDefault..` part means that it will return null if no matching element is found otherwise it will throw an exception if no element is found.

Comment: Also you will need to have curly braces after the `else` keyword, otherwise `DialogResult` will always be `OK`. It also seems unnecessary assign the `EventSelect` variable before the `else` keyword, as it will not be used inside the `if`scope